# Display resized image with good quality on every screen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I am trying to resize the image in PHP, it gets blurry on some screens. Is there any way to display resized image with good quality on every screen ?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
if($thumb == TRUE)
    {
        $thumbnail = $thumb_path.$fileName;
        list($width,$height) = getimagesize($upload_image);
        $thumb_create = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width,$thumb_height);
        switch($file_ext){
            case 'jpg':
                $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);
                break;
            case 'jpeg':
                $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);
                break;

            case 'png':
                $source = imagecreatefrompng($upload_image);
                break;
            case 'gif':
                $source = imagecreatefromgif($upload_image);
                break;
            default:
                $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);
        }

        imagecopyresized($thumb_create,$source,0,0,0,0,$thumb_width,$thumb_height,$width,$height);
        switch($file_ext){
            case 'jpg' || 'jpeg':
                imagejpeg($thumb_create,$thumbnail,100);
                break;
            case 'png':
                imagepng($thumb_create,$thumbnail,100);
                break;

            case 'gif':
                imagegif($thumb_create,$thumbnail,100);
                break;
            default:
                imagejpeg($thumb_create,$thumbnail,100);
        }
```

Comment: How do you resize your image?

Comment: what have you tried so far? show some code

Comment: with imagecopyresized() function.

Comment: This is my code -----
  imagecopyresized($thumb_create,$source,0,0,0,0,$thumb_width,$thumb_height,$width,$height);

Comment: @amanjha Update your post. Dont just comment it. :)

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve ? I took the time to edit your post and add your code there, you are welcome! However, your code is incomplete, you need to provide an example. We cannot really tell without a specific example in this case, unless somebody already had the exact same issue. What are the values of `$source, $thumb_width,‌​$thumb_height,$width‌` ​and `$height`

Comment: I have updated my post. After resizing image it looses its quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use image with high quality or you can even use `srcset`attribute for that.

**Example**

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="big.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="medium.jpg">
  <img src="small.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

[Try it](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_picture)

Comment: Happy to know, it worked for you.. Happy coding mate